# automatic backup for web deploy 3 (IIS) - to exclude folders in the backup

Tags: iis, msdeploy, webdeploy, microsoft-web-deploy

I have managed to setup Web Deploy Automatic Backups by following [this guide](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/web-deploy-automatic-backups), which works great.  However, in my websites I have a folder relative to the root `/uploads/` which contains all user-uploaded images which can be quite large.

The backup snapshot took a copy of that folder as well, and this results in huge backups.  Is it possible to exclude certain folders from the backup?

Comment: I have the same problem, for me however it's the app_data folder, and this pushes the backup above 4GB. Annoyingly, once it's above 4GB, it refuses to back it up anymore.

Comment: Why do you need to take backup of deployed app if you don't want to backup users' uploaded data? I mean, backups should be of database and uploaded files.

Answer (score 3):

There are skip parameters that you can use, try:

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:backupmanager -dest:backupmanager=<siteName>,uselast=true -skip:xpath=dirPath[@path='App_Data']
```

So basically add `-skip:xpath="/uploads/"`

Comment: I had to modify it slightly to be used in a publish profile, but your input combined with the example at https://github.com/entaconsulting/devs201508/blob/36f6ffab10fc6cf61c2100b401942ee6ea7a4642/WebApplication1/MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets.14.0.0/tools/VSToolsPath/Web/Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets worked perfectly.

Comment: Great :) feel free to accept it as answer or put your final working fix as answer.

Comment: Sadly I only added the bounty to this question and didn't create it myself, otherwise I definitely would.

Comment: Aaah I see, well no problem anyways!

Comment: @JordanRobinson How did you do it in a publish profile (pubxml file)? I don't know what the parameter is for the XML file. We have a directory of user-uploaded content that's over 30GB and I'd rather not back that up when publishing from VS.

Comment: @Vaindil The concept is pretty much the same, the syntax is just a bit different of course. Here's a gist: https://gist.github.com/JordanRobinson/40d6a6783221077a710b