# Microsoft Web Deploy backup fails and doesn't recover

Tags: c#, msdeploy, iis-10

I've recently started working with Microsoft Web Deploy.

I got backups working in a basic configuration and now I'd like to experiment with adding some folder exclusions to the `.pubxml` file in my projects based on [the comments to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32720312/3059082).

Here are my deploy settings:

```
    cd "\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\scripts\"
    . .\BackupScripts.ps1
    Reset-BackupSettings
    TurnOn-Backups -On $true
    Configure-Backups -Enabled $true
    Configure-Backups -ContinueSyncOnBackupFailure $false
    Configure-Backups -NumberOfBackups 5
    Configure-Backups -BackupPath "D:\UAT\AppBackups\{siteName}_snapshots"
    Configure-BackupSettingsProvider -CanAddExcludedProviders $true
    Get-BackupSettings
```

This works until I paste this snippet into my publish profile:

```
    <Target Name="AddCustomSkipRules"> 
      <ItemGroup>
        <MsDeploySkipRules Include="SkipAppDataFolder">
          <SkipAction></SkipAction>
          <ObjectName>dirPath</ObjectName>
          <AbsolutePath>$(_DestinationContentPath)\\App_Data$</AbsolutePath>
          <Apply>Destination</Apply>
          <XPath></XPath>
        </MsDeploySkipRules>
      </ItemGroup>
    </Target>
```

A publish attempt with that code fails, and then seems to get stuck.  Removing the snippet and republishing still fails.

Here's the error I get from the trace:

```
>trace eventLevel="Error" message="BACKUP_FAILED - Skipping backup because it failed due to an unknown reason.%C2%A0For more information, contact your server administrator."
```

```
AspNetModuleDiagErrorEvent  
Uri /msdeploy.axd  
  
User: username  
Client IP: 10.148.69.225  
Content-Type: application/msdeploy  
Version: 9.0.0.0  
MSDeploy.VersionMin: 7.1.600.0  
MSDeploy.VersionMax: 9.0.3802.0  
MSDeploy.Method: Sync  
MSDeploy.RequestId: fa27c81c-12aa-47f3-ac37-7ea94caa14a4  
MSDeploy.RequestCulture: en-US  
MSDeploy.RequestUICulture: en-US  
ServerVersion: 9.0.1973.0  
Skip: objectName="^configProtectedData$"  
Provider: auto, Path: A tracing deployment agent exception occurred that was propagated to the client.  
Request ID   'fa27c81c-12aa-47f3-ac37-7ea94caa14a4'.  
Request Timestamp: '11/10/2021 5:08:45 PM'.  
Error Details:  
    System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.  
    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.BackupManager.HandleExceptionForBackupFailure(DeploymentBaseContext baseContext, BackupSettings settings, Exception ex, Boolean suppressLogging)  
    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.BackupRuleHandler.PreSync(DeploymentSyncContext syncContext)  
    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.ProcessSync(DeploymentObject destinationObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)  
    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncToInternal(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions, PayloadTable payloadTable, ContentRootTable contentRootTable, Nullable``1 syncPassId, String syncSessionId)  
    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleSync(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData, Nullable`1 passId, String user, String siteName)  
    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleRequestWorker(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData)  
    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleRequest(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData)
```

Restarting IIS or the Web Deploy service doesn't help and I'd rather not restart the entire server if I can help it.

How can I get the backup service unstuck?

Comment: Need more information to reproduce your problem, did you check the web deploy logs in event viewer?

Comment: That's the only error that appears in the web deploy log.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem without more error messages, I suggest you open a [support ticket](https://support.microsoft.com) for this.